# Write on edges, treeplot MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I write on the lines that connects the vertices (edges) treeplot?

[image]

MATLAB code:

```
p(1)=0;
p(2)=1;p(3)=1;
p(6)=3;p(7)=3;
p(5)=2;p(4)=2;
p(10)=5;p(11)=5;
p(8)=4;p(9)=4;
p(16)=8;p(17)=9;
p(14)=7;p(15)=7;
p(20)=14;p(19)=14;
p(20)=15;p(19)=15;
%p.edgelable=0;
treeplot(p);
[x,y] = treelayout(p);
for i=1:length(y)
    text(x(i),y(i),strcat('a',num2str(i)))
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/162372-how-can-i-add-labels-to-the-tree-produced-by-the-treeplot-function-in-matlab-7-10-r2010a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mid-Point Between Children and Parent Nodes

The midpoints between the `Parent_Node` and the children can be calculated by taking the average of the two corresponding `x` and `y` positions. Then using the `text()` function as you already know. Adding the `'HorizontalAlignment'` property to `'center'` will also ensure the label's text is justified to the middle of the relative to the mid-point positions.

• X mid-point = (`x1` - `x2`) / 2 
• Y mid-point = (`y1` - `y2`) / 2

[image: Tree/Nodes Plot]

```
p(1)=0;
p(2)=1;p(3)=1;
p(6)=3;p(7)=3;
p(5)=2;p(4)=2;
p(10)=5;p(11)=5;
p(8)=4;p(9)=4;
p(16)=8;p(17)=9;
p(14)=7;p(15)=7;
p(20)=14;p(19)=14;
p(20)=15;p(19)=15;

treeplot(p);
[x,y] = treelayout(p);

for i=1:length(y)
    text(x(i),y(i),strcat('a',num2str(i)))
end

%Labelling branches%
for i = 2: length(p)
    Parent_Node = p(i);
    if(Parent_Node > 0)
        X_Midpoint = (x(i) + x(Parent_Node))/2;
        Y_Midpoint = (y(i) + y(Parent_Node))/2;
        text(X_Midpoint,Y_Midpoint,num2str(Parent_Node) + "->" + num2str(i),'HorizontalAlignment','center');
    end
end
```

Comment: Note: Not sure if the script was meant to re-assign the nodes `p(20)=14;p(19)=14;` to `p(20)=15;p(19)=15;`.

Comment: @itit123 No problem, consider accepting the answer by pressing the checkmark if this has sufficiently answered your question.